# cv.glmnet with Time Series Data

Tags: r, time-series, glmnet

I'm not sure if this has been asked but I can't seem to find anything regarding the question. Is it possible to use cv.glmnet for time series data? I currently have a blocked time series data frame and am using glmnet to determine the system. Wondering if I can use this correctly or need to use a different function for cross validation.

Comment: your features are the time points? what's your dependent variable?

Comment: They are time points. I am looking at the derivative for the x variable in a system of polynomials.